# Which Lists will/won't compile?

Tags: java, list

I've been looking at some old java test papers that I found in my college library. I came across this question.

> The code below contains four java code statements. Examine each line and determine whether and why it will cause a compile error or not.
>
> ```
> List[] myList1 = new List [5];         
> List myList2 = new List[5];
> List myList3 = new List();
> List myList5 = new Arraylist();
> ```

I'm stumped. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Just compile it and you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a valid array declaration.
The second one has an incorrect reference type.
In the third one, you cannot create an object of type List as it is an interface
For the last one, it's ArrayList, not Arraylist.

```
List[] myList2 = new List[5];
List myList5 = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the last one will compile, as that is a correct call / creation of a new `List` object. The first one should compile too because it is an alternate way of initializing a new `List` object.

This should be the correct syntax for the other two:

```
List[] myList2 = new List[5];
List myList3 = new ArrayList();
```

These are two ways of initializing a new List.

Comment: When I compiled it, the first one gave no errors, but the other three did. I assumed the first and last one were correct. This is why I asked the question, I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: My old answer was from reading some untrustable online source and I fixed my answer to hopefully help you understand better.